# Prevent Photoshop from trying to recover PSDs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-recovery

I've got a pretty old computer at work and that causes problems with photoshop.

When I boot up Photoshop, it always tries to load back the latest .psd file I had opened, as a recover (probably doesn't load the .psd file itself, just tries to remember how it was when Photoshop was closed.)

Thing is, sometimes those .psd are huge, and basically freeze my computer for 5 minutes when I'm loading them. So when I boot Photoshop for anything, it often tries to load that Freeze-for-5-minutes file, even if I just need PS to crop a small .jpg.

Is there an option, somewhere, that I could tick to tell Photoshop I don't want him to try and recover the old file? Every time I boot Photoshop, I want it blank or loaded with only the file I opened?

PS: I'm a web developer. I don't do changes and then try to save over it, PS is only to crop out things. So if PS crashes and I lose changes, I don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

Before opening Photoshop after a crash, delete all files inside the **AutoRecover** folder.

**Mac:**

HD/Users/*yourUser*/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop *Version*/AutoRecover

**Win:**

C:\Users\ *yourUser* \AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop *Version* \AutoRecover

---

Reset the Photoshop preferences:

**Preferences Panel** > **File Handling** > Uncheck **Automatically Save Recovery**...

Comment: Would there be a way to deny access to that folder? Like locking it up and making photoshop not able to write in the directory? Guess that question might go better on ServerFault now :p

Comment: You could make a batch script to clear that folder periodically I suppose?